# Vtiger CRM 6.4.0 - Issues when configuring Mail Manager

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am trying to setup an account on the  Mail Manager using "Others" mail server but when i click on the button Save button on the Setting menu it seems that the details has been saved but if refresh the page, Vtiger ask me to configure mailbox again. So the details that I have typed previously has not been saved and on database  "vtiger_mail_account" table is blank value.

Methods I have tested :

1. enable php_imap extension
2. Server Imap is also enable

How I can solve it ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check the vtiger logs and attach file here so i can check.

Answer (score 0):

```
Currently I am using vtiger 6.5 and i have same issue. I solve this by changing following seetings in php.ini 1)enable php_imap extension 2)later on check PHP_SAPI and update this in Vtigercron.php which is in yourvtigerdir/vtigercron.php  here you see this line 42 
in this line you need to change PHP_SAPI which is your sapi according to your php interface.3)You can check your sapi by echo PHP_SAPI; or echo '<pre>',print_r(php_sapi_name()),exit;
4)After above changes, Change 
  a) select organization type :: other
  b) Male server ip :: (enter your ip or mailser details)
  c) user name :: user or this mail as your personal mailid
  d) password  :: enter your own password.
  e) protocol  :: IMAP2 or IMAP4 (check by changing protocol)
  f) SSL options :: At starting level Use NO TLS.
  g) Certification validation :: Validate cert.
  f) referesh time :: 5
```